# Manage Kickstart library with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I maintain a library of different kickstart configurations, mostly for CentOS 5 and 6. It has recently gotten to the point I want to deduplicate as much of this information as possible.

I am aware of a couple options out there which can dynamically generate kickstart files. Not interested at this point unless I really need to do that route. I would like to create my Kickstart files using a template along the following line:

deploy1-centos5.erb

```
....
install=http://.../$arch/...
repo=http://.../$arch/...
....
```

My output naming schema is "deploy1-centos5-x86_64".

I'd like to be able to create several kickstart files from a given template, one for 32 bit, one 64, ppc, etc. This would work **perfectly** if I could readily set the value of *arch* per each time the template is called to create a file.

What is the most ready way to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest pattern is to create a define that'll spit out the file you want based on your inputs.

```
define kickstart::config ($os, $arch) {

# $name is a reserved variable, it works based on the name of this define
# kickstart::configs { "this_becomes_name": }

  file { "kickstart/conf.d/${name}-${os}-${arch}":
    ensure  => present,
    content => template("kickstart/conf.d/${name}.erb"),
    #content => template("kickstart/conf.d/${name}-${os}.erb"),
    #content => template("kickstart/conf.d/${name}-${os}-${arch}.erb"),
    # or whatever, but this template file will need to exists. 
  }

}
```

and then apply like

```
kickstart::config { 'deploy1':
  arch => 'i386',
  os   => 'centos5',
}
```